# Google Doc Spreadsheet, using formula to get two pieces of data from the same cell

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using a Good Doc Spreadsheet and I have a cell that has this data in it:

2 Sponsored Bills (Ranks 99 of 99) 0 Made Into Law (Ranks 12 of 99)

This data is being imported with ImportHTML, so it's a constantly changing fluid cell.

Is there a way for me to pull the 2 from the Sponsored Bill portion and place that in a cell all of its own and pull the separate 0 made into law and put that number into a different cell?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are many people here willing to help, but please make sure you've showed what you've tried, what didn't work, and the context of your question. Please make sure you've read [**how-to-ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and then edit your question to better attract people's expenditure of time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your data is in cell A1.
To get the first number, use

```
=mid(A1,find("Sponsored Bills",A1)-2,1)
```

And to get the second value, use

```
=mid(A1,find("Made Into Law",A1)-2,1)
```

find() finds where that text is in the cell and then we move back 2 spaces and grab one character.